# Series for $\left|\frac{f(x)}{x-a}\right|^z$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

> Let $f:\mathbb{R\to R}$ be a smooth function and suppose that it has a unique zero at $x=a$. For every $z\in\mathbb{C}$, define a function $f_z(x)=\left|\frac{f(x)}{x-a}\right|^z$. Find an expansion for $f_z(x)$.

If $z$ was real I could put it inside the absolute value and try to find a Taylor series for $f_z(x)$. However, since $z$ can have a non-zero imaginary part it's not possible and in fact $f_z(x)$ isn't analytic.  Can I find an explicit expansion for $f_z(x)$?

**EDIT:** In fact, can we think on $f_z$ as a function which is analytic in $|\cdot|^z$ and expand it to $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n|x-a|^{nz}$?

Comment: How do you suggest to define $$a^z$$ for $a$ real nonnegative and $z$ complex? For example, $$1^i=(e^{42\pi i})^i=e^{-42\pi}\ ?$$

Comment: @Did , what do you mean? We take the eigenvalue and then this can't happen. I just wonder why $f_z(x)$ is analytic, that's all...

Comment: "eigenvalue" Hmmm, sorry but this does not make any sense ("eigenvalues" refers to matrices, where do you see any matrix?). My demand for explanations stands and, unless you address it, there is no question here since your function $f_z$ is simply **undefined**.

Comment: @Did I meant absolute value of course :) Like $z^\alpha$ with $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ has Laurent expansion, I want to extend it to $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$. Can it be done? To your question, I want it to be some sort of "taking the principal branch" like we do when defining $\log z$.

Comment: If you are thinking of a way to define unambiguously $$u^z$$ for $u$ real and $z$ complex then provide it. Note that a priori you need to obtain a regular function of $u$ around $u=0$.

Comment: @Did. Let $Log$ denote the principal branch of complex $\log$. By virtue of $Log_a z=\frac{Log z}{Log a}$ one defines $|a|^i$ as the inverse of $Log_a$ (that is $Log_a z=i⇒|a|^i=z$).

Comment: Then you realize the function one obtains is not even continuous at $z=0$, right?

Comment: @Did but like $\log(1+z)$ has an expansion when $z\neq -1$, so this function should have one. If I knew that $f_z\neq 0$ for all $x$, that would imply it has an expansion, right?

Comment: Again, $z\mapsto\mathrm{Log}(1+z)$ is not even continuous at $z=-4$.